# One hot encoding characters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there a possibilty to one-hot encode characters of a text in Tensorflow or Keras?

- `tf.one_hot` seem to take only integers.
- `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot` seems to one-hot encode sentences
  to words, but not to characters.

Beside that, `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot` works really strange, since the response does not really seem one-hot encoded, since the following code:

```
text = "ab bba bbd"
res = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot(text=text,n=3)
print(res)
```

Lead to this result:

```
[1,2,2]
```

Every time I run this program, the output is a different 3d vector, sometimes it is `[1,1,1]` or `[2,1,1]`. The documentation says, that unicity is not guaranteed, but this seems really senseless to me.

Comment: I created now a manual mapping between all possible characters and an integer, and then I can use the integer with tf.one_hot() to get my encoding. But this is a little bit complicated way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a nice answer based on pure python, unfortunately I do not find the source anymore. It first converts every char to an int, and then replaces the int with an one-hot array. It has unicity over the whole program, even over all programms if the alphabet is the same length and the same order.

```
    # Is the alphabet of all possible chars you want to convert
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

    def convert_to_onehot(data):
        #Creates a dict, that maps to every char of alphabet an unique int based on position
        char_to_int = dict((c,i) for i,c in enumerate(alphabet))
        encoded_data = []
        #Replaces every char in data with the mapped int
        encoded_data.append([char_to_int[char] for char in data])
        print(encoded_data) # Prints the int encoded array

        #This part now replaces the int by an one-hot array with size alphabet
        one_hot = []
        for value in encoded_data:
            #At first, the whole array is initialized with 0
            letter = [0 for _ in range(len(alphabet))]
            #Only at the number of the int, 1 is written
            letter[value] = 1
            one_hot.append(letter)
        return one_hot

   print(convert_to_onehot("hello world"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use keras `to_categorical`

```py
import tensorflow as tf
# define the document
text = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'
# estimate the size of the vocabulary
words = set(tf.keras.preprocessing.text.text_to_word_sequence(text))
vocab_size = len(words)
print(vocab_size)
# integer encode the document
result = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(tf.keras.preprocessing
                                         .text.one_hot(text, round(vocab_size*1.3)))
print(result)
```

Result

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: Thank you, but for me this does not really work. "quick" and "lazy" get the same number, although they are not equal words. As I said, documentation says unicity is not guranteed, but this makes it useless, from a developer point, isn't it?

Comment: @user3921232 The unicity not guaranteed but is due to hashing, in reality it has a very little impact the collisions aren't large for good hash functions. I can't see where 'lazy' and 'quick' I attached the result of running the example above and it's unique.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand, thank you! I see, but if I run your program, I always get a collision of quick and lazy. I use the newest version of keras and tensorflow. In the meantime I found a different solution, I will post it as answer, but it seems like yours is the shorter and official version!

Comment: It seems to me that "The" and "the" got the same number, which is ok?